# Python: How to access string key in dictionary from a dictionary of lists using index 0 on each list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to iterate through, say, dict1, which has keys to lists of two items, strings. There is another dictionary (dict2) with four entries. These entries have keys that are the four only possible strings within the lists in the dict1. As I iterate through dict1, I want the program to pick out the first item in the list and then find that key in dict2, so I can access their integer values based on what I iterate through. The strings are the same, so if accessed properly it should work? Here's my code:

```
hogwarts_students = { "A" : ["Gryffindor", "Slytherin"],"B" : ["Hufflepuff", "Ravenclaw"],"C" : ["Ravenclaw", "Hufflepuff"],"D" : ["Slytherin", "Ravenclaw"]}
top_choice = 0
second_choice = 0
no_choice = 0
houses = {"Gryffindor" : 0, "Hufflepuff" : 0, "Ravenclaw" : 0,
"Slytherin" : 0}
def sorting_hat(students):
    for student in hogwarts_students:
        if houses[student][0] <= len(hogwarts_students) / 4:
```

Am I accessing the integer value that corresponds with the first item of the lists within dict1 properly on that last line? Is there another way of doing this that is better?

Comment: Does it work? Then it's fine.

Comment: You're going to get an issue with the key (student in your for loop) potentially not being in your houses dictionary. Add in something to check for that.

Other than that, if it works, I don't see any issues with the code you posted.

Comment: Your loop iterator will set the student to the key values from your hogwarts_students dictionary.  Thus it will have values "A", "B", etc.  You will get a key value error in the test as the houses dictionary has no key "A", "B", etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve mentioned in his comment, your iterator `student` will be iterating over the keys from `hogwarts_students` ('A', 'B', 'C', ...). This will cause a key error in your `if` statement since it will try to access `houses['A']` which does not exist.

I would recommend using `.items()` to iterate over the keys and values of `hogwarts_students` at the same time like:

```
for student, house_options in hogwarts_students.items():
    first_option = house_options[0]
    if houses[first_option] <= len(hogwarts_students) // 4:
        # Do something
        pass
```

Also you have this set up as a function that takes a `students` parameter. If `students` is going to take the place of `hogwarts_students` then make sure you are referencing the `students` dictionary inside your function rather than the `hogwarts_students` variable.

```
def sorting_hat(students):
    for student, house_options in students.items():
        first_option = house_options[0]
        if houses[first_option] <= len(students) // 4:
            # Do something
            pass
```